# How to setup a xamarin API SQL database

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, api, xamarin

First a little summery, I am trying to make an app that has a connection to the database and that can update realtime a website. So you can see realtime the scoreboard.

First I have made in microsoft SQL server manager a database with the following query:

```
create Database EscapeGebruikers

Use EscapeGebruikers
create table Challenger 
(
    ChallengerID int identity not null,
    AantalPers int not null,
    TeamNaam varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (ChallengerID)
);

Use EscapeGebruikers
create table Ranking
(
    RankID int identity not null,
    ChallengerID int not null,
    ScoreMin tinyint not null,
    ScoreSec tinyint not null,
    DateAchieved datetime not null,
    primary key (RankID)
);

Use EscapeGebruikers
create table Wachtwoorden 
(
    ID int not null Identity Primary key,
    Wachtwoord varchar(128) not null,
    Beschrijving varchar(255)
);

Delete from GroepTijd where TeamNaam = 'Pannenkoeken'

Select * from Ranking
select * from Challenger
select * from Wachtwoorden
```

It's an easy database keep track of teams who use the app, this app will only be destributed on 1 tablet. So there is not much traffic or so what. It keeps track of amount of persons, the teamname they choose, the time they set (scoremin = minutes, scoresec = seconds) so I can represent the score in minutes and seconds, and the date they achieved this score.

So what I am trying for some time is to send and read data with the app. With xamarin entry I try to send data to the database. I have seen that you could write directly to the database, but this is less secure. So the suggested way I have read was to use an API. I am not familiar with API's but I have found a great tutorial: [Tutorial I followed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51246.fun-with-xamarin-building-a-simple-working-memory-game-app-with-web-api-and-signalr.aspx)

This tutorial is exact what I needed so I followed and changed code so it would match my database with names and functions. This is what I have when the button in the form is clicked:

```
using System;
using EscapeHaarlem.Classes;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace EscapeHaarlem.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PasswordPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PasswordPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        }
        async void CheckExistingProfileAndSave(string teamnaam)
        {
            if (Utils.IsConnectedToInternet())
            {
                try
                {
                    PlayerData player = await PlayerManager.CheckExistingPlayer(teamnaam);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(player.TeamNaam))
                    {
                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Email does not exist.", "OK");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Settings.TeamTeamNaam = entryTeamNaam.Text.Trim();
                        Settings.AantalPers = Int32.Parse(entryAantalPers.Text);
                        Settings.DateAchieved = player.DateAchieved;
                        App.Current.MainPage = new RedButton(entryTeamNaam.Text);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops", "An error occured while connecting to the server. Please check your connection.", "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "No internet connection.", "OK");
            }

            btnLogin.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        void Save()
        {
            Settings.TeamTeamNaam = entryTeamNaam.Text.Trim();
            Settings.AantalPers = Int32.Parse(entryAantalPers.Text);
            App.Current.MainPage = new RedButton(entryTeamNaam.Text);
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (entryWachtwoord.Text == "admin" && Int32.Parse(entryAantalPers.Text) > 2 && Int32.Parse(entryAantalPers.Text) < 7 && entryTeamNaam.Text.Length > 1)
                CheckExistingProfileAndSave(entryTeamNaam.Text);
            else
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Let op!", "Groepsgrootte is 3 tot 6 deelnemers. Indien aan deze voorwaarde is voldaan is het wachtwoord niet correct. Kom je er niet uit vraag de begeleider om hulp!", "Okay");
        }
    }
}
```

So if I understand it correctly, when the button is pressed the teamname should be checked if there is already an entry in the database with that teamname. If so you can't use that teamname. In the try catch statement from function `CheckExistingProfileAndSave` it will run the catch error. So something went wrong, I am not sure what went wrong.

When I try to debug this code with breakpoints it does run `PlayerData player = await PlayerManager.CheckExistingPlayer(teamnaam);`. So I followed this path `CheckExistingPlayer`.

This led me to the follwing code block:

```
 public async static Task<PlayerData> CheckExistingPlayer(string teamnaam)
        {
            REST.GameAPI api = new REST.GameAPI();
            PlayerData player = new PlayerData();

            if (Utils.IsConnectedToInternet())
            {
                player = await api.GetPlayerData(teamnaam);
            }

            return player;
        }
```

Where I set again breakpoints to find out it does the function inside the if statement. So again I followed it where this led me.

This is the following code:

```
 public async Task<PlayerData> GetPlayerData(string teamnaam)
        {
            var uri = new Uri($"{APIUri}/GetPlayerProfile?teamnaam={teamnaam}");
            PlayerData player = null;

            var response = await ProcessGetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                player = new PlayerData();
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerData>(content);
            }

            return player;
        }
```

And this is the part where it goes wrong I think. `var response = await ProcessGetAsync(uri);` this part code sends the uri that is made up as following:

```
var uri = new Uri($"{APIUri}/GetPlayerProfile?teamnaam={teamnaam}");
```

I do not have yet a domain name so I am not sure what should be in the place of APIUri. But I found out that there are free API's you could use, so I used for the APIUri the follwing: `private const string APIUri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";`.

After this is send the full uri goes to:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessGetAsync(Uri uri)
{
    return await client.GetAsync(uri);
}
```

Sad enough this won't get or set the database in any way.

Hope someone could tell me what's wrong and why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure why you needed to post that much code that has nothing to do with your problem.  "I do not have yet a domain name' - then use the IP of your server.

Comment: I did try that as well but still got the same error.

Comment: What error?  You didn't post any error or exception details in your question.

Comment: The "error" I am talking about is the in the try catch statment with the display alert.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` and look at the contents of the `ex` object to see what the actual problem is

Comment: The error is: "System.NullReferanceException: object referance not set to an instance of an object. At EscapeHaarlem.Views.PasswordPage+<CheckExistingProfileAndSave>d_2.MoveNext()[0x000d1] in FILEPATH

Comment: You have a null ref.  The stack trace should tell you which specific line causes it, otherwise you can step through your code in the debugger to find it.

Comment: Yes, it had to do with if(string.isnullorempty(player.TeamNaam)) what gives the error